# PYTHON several times print from a reference file

Tags: python, string, file, reference, repeat

I have a question about python programming.

If I have a reference file (ref.txt) like

```
3
5
6
```

I want to make a output file like if I want to 5 times these strings

```
3
5
6
3
5
6
3
5
6
3
5
6
3
5
6
```

total 15 rows.

I have thought a code like

```
with open('ref.txt') as f1, open('out.txt', 'w') as f2:
     for i in range(1, 6):
           for line in f1:
               value=line.split()
               line=' '.join(value) + '\n'

               f2.write(line)
```

This code just print the original value. How do I print multiple repeat lines of reference value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
repeat = ""
with open('ref.txt') as f1:
    for line in f1:
        repeat = "".join([repeat, line])
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f2:
    f2.write(repeat*5)
```

Comment: This printed out 333335555566666 instead of 356356356356356. Is there any method?

Comment: When I used this, Type error: join() takes exactly one argument happened. Also, I put : after f1. When I remove repeat in join(), there is nothing printed. Would you please check this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Stephan's answer explains how to do this, but doesn't explain what's wrong with your attempt:

```
with open('ref.txt') as f1, open('out.txt', 'w') as f2:
     for i in range(1, 6):
           for line in f1:
               value=line.split()
               line=' '.join(value) + '\n'

               f2.write(line)
```

You have a minor problem, in that `range(1, 6)` only has 5 values in it (`print` it out and see); you want `range(6)` here.

But the major problem here is that you're only opening `ref.txt` once, but trying to iterate through it repeatedly. You can't to that with files, or any other kind of iterator. The whole point of an iterator gets "used up" when you iterate through it.

There are four basic solutions to this:

---

If you have a way to "reset" the iterator, you can do that each time through the loop. Most iterators can't do that, but files can, with `seek`:

```
with open('ref.txt') as f1, open('out.txt', 'w') as f2:
    for i in range(6):
        for line in f1:
            value=line.split()
            line=' '.join(value) + '\n'
            f2.write(line)
        f1.seek(0)
```

---

Alternatively, if you can (cheaply enough) get a new, clean iterator each time through the loop, you can just do that. In this case, that just means opening the file each time:

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f2:
    for i in range(6):
        with open('ref.txt') as f1:
            for line in f1:
                value=line.split()
                line=' '.join(value) + '\n'
                f2.write(line)
```

---

Alternatively, in some cases, you have a reusable iterable (like a `list`) sitting around that you got the iterator from, and you can just use that instead of the iterator. But that doesn't apply here.

---

Finally, you can *create* a reusable iterable by storing up the values in a `list`, or some other repeatable type like a string. For example:

```
with open('ref.txt') as f1:
    lines = list(f1)
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f2:
    for i in range(6):
        for line in lines:
            value=line.split()
            line=' '.join(value) + '\n'
            f2.write(line)
```

You may want to move some or all of the processing into the first block, so you don't do it 6 times in a row. For example:

```
with open('ref.txt') as f1:
    lines = [' '.join(line.split()) + '\n' for line in f1]
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f2:
    for i in range(6):
        for line in lines:
            f2.write(line)
```

Once you've got that, you can improve it further:

```
with open('ref.txt') as f1:
    lines = [' '.join(line.split()) + '\n' for line in f1]
data = ''.join(lines)
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f2:
    for i in range(6):
        f2.write(data)
```

And even further:

```
with open('ref.txt') as f1:
    lines = [' '.join(line.split()) + '\n' for line in f1]
data = ''.join(lines)
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f2:
    f2.write(data * 6)
```

Comment: This is extremely good for understanding what I did miss and the code. Than you very much for your help.